# REACT: multiple call to action in infoWindow google maps

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

In a react application (with styled component), I created a map with the Google API (no library/package used) and on this map, there are several markers and then infowindow. Each location can have 1 or more call to action in it's infowindow. I manage to display the call to actions with the correct labels but **the click actions do nothing at all** (I also tried a simple console.log on the click but it doesn’t work at all) while a link () works as expected

Here is how I implement the **google map component** :

```
function GoogleMap (props) {

    // PROPS
    const { locations, onMapLoaded } = props;

    GoogleMap.propTypes = {
        intl: intlShape,
        lang: langType.isRequired,
        company: companyType.isRequired,
        locations: PropTypes.arrayOf(
            locType.isRequired
        ).isRequired,
        onMapLoaded: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };

    // Variables
    const markerSize = 40;
    const theme = useTheme();
    const markers = locations;

    const mapRef = useRef(null);
    const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'AIz...my ACCESS_TOKEN';
    const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
    const [infoWindow, setInfoWindow] = useState(null);
  
    // Functions
    function getMapStyle (theme, onBackground)  {
        switch (theme.branding.palette_type) {
          case PALETTE_TYPE_ANALOGOUS:
                return getMapLightStyle(theme);
          case PALETTE_TYPE_MONOCHROMATIC:
                return isLight(onBackground) ? getMapDarkStyle(theme) : getMapLightStyle(theme);
          default:
                return null; // or any other fallback value
        }
      }

    /*
    * Create and inject google map in the mapRef and create infoWindow
    * --
    */
    function initializeMap () {

         null;

        const light = tint(0.98, theme.colors.main);
        const dark = shade(0.8, theme.colors.main);
        const onBackground = readableColor(theme.colors.main, light, dark);

        const mapStyle = getMapStyle(theme, onBackground);

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const mapOptions = {
                center: { lat: 0, lng: 0 },
                zoom: 1,
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                styles: mapStyle
          };
          if (mapRef.current) {
                const googleMap = new window.google.maps.Map(mapRef.current, mapOptions);
                const googleInfoWindow = new window.google.maps.InfoWindow({
              pixelOffset: new window.google.maps.Size(0, -markerSize - markerSize / 4)
                });
      
                setMap(googleMap);
                setInfoWindow(googleInfoWindow);
                onMapLoaded(googleMap);
                resolve(); // Resolve the promise when the map is initialized
          }
            else {
                reject(new Error('Map container reference is not available.'));
          }
        });
      }

    /*
    * On mount, check if google map script exists (to avoid duplicate scripts)
    * Inject in the DOM google map script
    * --
    */
    useEffect(() => {
        const scriptExists = document.querySelector(`script[src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${ACCESS_TOKEN}&libraries=geometry"]`);
    
        if (!scriptExists) {
          const script = document.createElement('script');
          script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${ACCESS_TOKEN}&libraries=geometry`;
          script.async = true;
          script.defer = true;
          script.onload = initializeMap;
          document.body.appendChild(script);
        }
        else {
          initializeMap();
        }
    
        return () => {
          if (scriptExists) {
                scriptExists.parentNode.removeChild(scriptExists);
          }
        };
      }, []);
    
    /*
    * Iterate markers regarging props.locations
    * Inject react component in static info window (for each marker)
    * Fit the map bounds regarding markers
    * --
    */
      useEffect(() => {
        const MESSAGES = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('__MESSAGES').innerText);

        if (map && markers.length > 0) {

          markers.forEach((markerData) => {
                const marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
              position: { lat: markerData.geo_loc.geo.lat, lng: markerData.geo_loc.geo.lon },
              map: map,
              icon: {
                        url: getIconStyle(theme),
                        anchor: new window.google.maps.Point(markerSize / 2, markerSize),
                        scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(markerSize, markerSize)
              }
                });
    
                marker.addListener('click', () => {
                    const { lang, company, intl } = props;
                    // The ReactDOMServer object enables you to render components to static markup 
                    const content =  ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
                        <IntlProvider locale={lang} messages={MESSAGES}>
                            <Provider value={{ lang, company }} >
                                <MapInfoWindow company={company} theme={theme} lang={lang} location={markerData} intl={intl} i18n={i18n}/>
                            </Provider>
                        </IntlProvider>
                    );

                    infoWindow.setContent(content);
                    infoWindow.setPosition(marker.getPosition());
                    infoWindow.open(map);
                });
          });
    
          const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          markers.forEach((markerData) => {
                bounds.extend(new window.google.maps.LatLng(markerData.geo_loc.geo.lat, markerData.geo_loc.geo.lon));
          });
    
          if (markers.length === 1) {
                map.setCenter({ lat: markers[0].lat, lng: markers[0].lng });
                map.setZoom(12);
          }
            else {
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
          }
    
          map.addListener('click', () => {
                if (infoWindow) {
              infoWindow.close();
                }
          });
        }
      }, [map, markers, infoWindow, mapRef]);
  
    return <Root ref={mapRef} />;
}
  

export default injectIntl(GoogleMap);
```

And the **MapInfoWindow component** :

```
function MapInfoWindow (props) {

    // PROPS
    const { lang, intl, i18n, location, company, theme } = props;
    
    MapInfoWindow.propTypes = {
        intl: intlShape,
        company: companyType,
        lang: langType.isRequired,
        location: PropTypes.object,
        theme: themeType.isRequired,
        i18n: PropTypes.node
    };

    // State
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(null);

    const ctaLocList = computeCtaList(location, setShowModal);

    // Functions

    function closeModal () {
        setShowModal(null);
    }
    function renderLocationActions () {

        return (
          <React.Fragment>
                <LocationActions>
                  {ctaLocList.map((item) => {
                        const { cta } = item;
                        const { action, label } = cta;

                      return (
                            <Button
                                key={`list-item-cta-0-${label}`}
                                action={action}
                                label={label}
                                size={BUTTON_SIZE_SMALL}
                            />
                      );
                  })}
                  </LocationActions>
            </React.Fragment>
        );

    }

    function computeCtaList (selectedLocation, setShowModal) {

        return [].concat(
    
            // TABLE_BOOKING
            selectedLocation.table_booking?.enabled === true ? {
                cta: {
                    label: intl.formatMessage({ id: i18n['cta.TABLE_BOOKING_title'] }),
                    action: () => { setShowModal('table-booking'); }
    
                }
            } : [],
    
            // GIFT_CARDS
            selectedLocation.gift_cards?.enabled === true ? {
                cta: {
                    label: intl.formatMessage({ id: i18n['cta.GIFT_CARDS_title'] }),
                    action: () => { setShowModal('gift-cards'); }
                }
            } : [],
    
            // FOOD_ORDER
            selectedLocation.food_order?.enabled === true ? {
                cta: {
                    label: intl.formatMessage({ id: i18n['cta.FOOD_ORDER_title'] }),
                    action: () => setShowModal('food-order')
                }
            } : [],
    
            // ROOM_BOOKING
            selectedLocation.room_booking?.enabled === true ? {
                cta: {
                    label: intl.formatMessage({ id: i18n['cta.ROOM_BOOKING_title'] }),
                    action: () => { setShowModal('room-booking'); }
                }
            } : [],
    
            // EVENT_VENUE
            selectedLocation.event_venue?.enabled === true ? {
                cta: {
                    label: intl.formatMessage({ id: i18n['cta.VENUE_BOOKING_title'] }),
                    action: getPathToPageById('venue-booking', lang)
                }
            } : [],
    
            // APPOINTMENT
            selectedLocation.appointments?.enabled === true ? {
                cta: {
                    label: intl.formatMessage({ id: i18n['cta.APPOINTMENT_title'] }),
                    action: () => { setShowModal('appointment'); }
                }
            } : []
        );
    }
    

    const name = location.company_specific_name || location.name;
    const action = getPathToPageById('location', lang, { location_id: location.id });
    const hours = location.hours.hours;

    const mobileNumber = location.mobile?.international || company?.mobile?.international || null;
    const phoneNumber = location.phone?.international || company?.phone?.international || null;

    const phoneNumbers = new Intl.ListFormat(lang, { type: 'disjunction', style: 'long' }).format([mobileNumber, phoneNumber].filter(p => p !== null));

    const hasCtaList= !!ctaLocList?.length;

    const openInfo = getOpenInfoStatus(location, lang) || {};
    const { status } = openInfo;

    const badgeLabel = status ? intl.formatMessage({ id: i18n[`opening_status.${status.toLowerCase()}`] }) : intl.formatMessage({ id: i18n[`opening_status.${isLocationOpened(hours.hours) ? 'open' : 'closed'}`] });

    
    return (
        <BrowserRouter basename={`/${lang}/`}>
            <Base company={company} theme={theme} is_preview={false}>
                <Switch>
                    <>
                        <Root>
                            <Card>
                                <CardMain as={InternalLink} to={action} hasCtaList={hasCtaList}>
                                    <CardHeader> 
                                        <LocationName>{name}</LocationName>
                                        <Badge label={badgeLabel} isImportant={status ? true : false}/>
                                    </CardHeader>
                                    <CardContent>
                                        <CardContentItem>
                                            <Address company={company} location={location}/>
                                        </CardContentItem>
                                        <CardContentItem>
                                            {phoneNumbers}
                                        </CardContentItem>
                                    </CardContent>
                                </CardMain>
                                {hasCtaList ? renderLocationActions() : null}
                            </Card>
                        </Root>
                        <ModalsObjective
                            company={company}
                            lang={lang}
                            showModal={showModal}
                            location={location}
                            onClose={closeModal}
                        />
                    </>
                </Switch>
            </Base>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default injectIntl(MapInfoWindow);
```

Here is a visual of what it look like for now :

So as I said before, everything is working as expected, the only issue the cta(s) in the infoWindow that are not working while a link () works as expected

[Screenshot of google map implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8aeB.png)

Comment: Can you provide a working codesandbox for this one?